# How many active key can I have for a single account?

Tags: keys, active-key, owner-key

I know  I can import as many key as I want in my EOS account. At least there  should be one owner key and active key pairs. There is  Only one owner key pair, My question is How many active key pairs are present simultanously for a single account?